# How to measure energy consumption of Apache Spark and Flink

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-flink

How to measure energy consumption of Apache Spark and Flink
are there any tool or technology to measure the energy consumption of Spark and Flink

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow !
Apache spark and Flink are frameworks that are used for distributed computing and stream processing respectively.There is nothing like frameworks consuming computational power.

If I get your intention correct, you were asking about computational power consumption of applications which were developed using above frameworks.

So, answering that, generally such applications are deployed in any any on the servers / cloud providers. These cloud providers give in built metrics to track the CPU / memory consumption.

If you are running these applications on you local, you can use tools like `jprofiler`, `jconsole`, `visualVM`. These tools gives you visual representation of CPU consumption, memory consumption etc.

**P.S:**
A software framework is an abstraction in which software providing generic functionality can be selectively changed by additional user-written code, thus providing application-specific software.

Distributed computing,stream processing or say any computation can be implemented with out the above frameworks. But it will be chaos. Framework makes a dev's life easy. There are trade offs coming along with ease due to over abstraction, that is a different discussion as a whole.